# Stripe Card API and Apple pay / Gpay

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, applepay, google-pay

I am currently implementing apple pay on my application and I saw on the Stripe Card payment API the following field :

> **tokenization_method (string)** :
> If the card number is tokenized, this is the method that was used. Can be android_pay (includes Google Pay), apple_pay, masterpass, visa_checkout, or null.

From this field, I understand that there is a way to create a card with the apple / gpay token in order to have the response object filled with `tokenization_method: apple_pay` or `tokenization_method: android_pay` or did I miss something ?

Did anybody used that API before and could provide some enlightment please ?  I'm REALLY struggling on this and didn't find anything on this so far ...

EDIT : I reformuled my question since it was missleading

Answer (score 1):

That is a field that is returned as part of a retrieved object, not something you provide as part of creating it.

Comment: That is right, My question was probably wrong, but how should I create the Card Object with the Apple / Gpay token (and have that field returned with the apple_pay or android_pay inside)

Comment: You can implement them on the web like this: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button